# update a cell in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

My code reads cities array to a `tableView`.

- When a cell is clicked, it move to a `SecondViewController`. The `SecondViewController` has a button.
- If I clicked the button, it will display an image into that cell.

> **Problem:** I am trying to update the cell whenever the button is clicked. It is working but no matter which cell is clicked, it always displays the image for cell 3, if I clicked again it displays for cell number 1 image.

How to fix this so that when the button is clicked, it display the image for it's cell and if the same cell is clicked, hide the image.

My codes:

```
var first = 0
var reload = false
var cellNumber: Int!

var cities:[String] = ["paris", "moscow", "milan","rome","madrid","garda","barcelona"]

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
// func to reload a cell
@objc func toReload(rowNumber: Int){
    reload = true

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowNumber , section: 0)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}

// load tableview from a SecondViewController call
@objc func loadList(notification: NSNotification){

    self.tableView.reloadData() // reload tableview
    toReload(rowNumber: cellNumber)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cities.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomCell

    cell.label1.text = cities[indexPath.row]

    let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "20870718")! // assign imageView to an image

    if first == 0 {
       cell.myimage.isHidden = true // hide image
        first = 1 // condition to never enter again
    }

    if reload == true {

        if cell.myimage.isHidden == true {
             cell.myimage.image = image
             cell.myimage.isHidden = false
        }
        else{
            cell.myimage.isHidden = true
        }
        reload = false

    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.cellNumber = indexPath.row

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "send", sender: self)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.reloadData()

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
    // call load list method
}
```

}

SecondViewController:

```
@IBAction func displayImage(_ sender: Any) {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)

}
```

Comment: Well one thing to keep in mind is that `self.tableView.reloadData()` will reload everything so even though it seems like you wanted to only reload a specific row, the whole table will reload. However, even with that change, I think you should reconsider how you are keeping track which button is pressed. Maybe it would be better to send an object with the notification from the SecondViewController that indicates which button was pressed?

Comment: I reload the whole tableview again once the button is clicked because im calling from another viewcontroller . So if I did not, it will be nil. So I reload it then I update the specific row. @R. Lin

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your `cellForRowAt`.when secondViewController notify the first one no matter which cell you are reloading `cellForRowAt` always will be called because when you scroll tableView wants to recuse cell and `reload == true` becomes true for all cells.so you have to check if `indexPath.row == cellNumber` then do the rest work :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomCell
   cell.label1.text = cities[indexPath.row]
   let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "20870718")! // assign imageView to an image
   if first == 0 {
      cell.myimage.isHidden = true // hide image
      first = 1 // condition to never enter again
   }
   if indexPath.row == cellNumber {
     if reload == true {
        if cell.myimage.isHidden == true {
          cell.myimage.image = image
          cell.myimage.isHidden = false
        }
        else {
            cell.myimage.isHidden = true
        }
        reload = false
      }
   }
   return cell
}
```

Comment: what u did fix one problem thanks. the problem now is that how to know if the image is displayed or hidden for a specific cell. what i did here is wrong ( if cell.myimage.isHidden == true { ) @andesta.erfan

Comment: @callmeAL that's another question please explain about your problem i didn't get it , you are checking if the image is hidden or not for that cell where is the problem?